# I need help solving this problem regarding charge conservation and electric current.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/244ED.png)

I think that part (a) is asking "What can be inferred by applying conservation of charge to an arbitrary control volume?

I found the following breakdown that I think helps answer part (a), but I have no idea how to do part (b).

[Solution to part (a)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGJg.png)

Thanks guys!

Comment: I added the "physics" and "mathematical-physics" tags to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

By electroneutrality, $0\approx\partial_t\rho_e=-\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=\kappa_e\nabla^2\phi$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? And does that answer part b?

Comment: @Jasen It is (b), yes. Electroneutrality is only needed to approximate any of this as $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I still don't totally understand how this shows the PDE that governs Φ(r,t) though. I understand that electroneutrality causes ρ to be 0. But where is the ∂t coming from? Also, how exactly are the two equations getting tied together?

Comment: @Jasen Technically it's possible for $\rho_e$ to be small but $\partial_t\rho_e$ not to be, if e.g. $\rho_e$ oscillates at high frequency, but a physicist expects this not to apply in conditions described as electroneutral. The rest is the continuity equation.